# Combining LDOs in an effort to increase current

Tags: power, buck, ldo

Is there any way to combine 2 (or more) similar LDOs with fixed output voltage so the total output current would be increased?
Buying another LDO is possible but I have a large stock of 1A LDOs and I need 3A.

Comment: What is an LDO?

Comment: Experienced EE guys needn't answer my question.

Comment: Perhaps if they have foldback current limit then there is a reasonable chance it will work.  But in general current sharing will not be even.

Comment: it is a lot cheaper if you can make the LDO switch an external transistor. Also perhaps there are some manufacturers that make LDOs with the "parallel" feature, I swear i've seen it before while going through a bunch of LDOs at one point. 3A though might be hard and not very cost effective just by stacking them. It's far better in terms of board space and cost to get a DC-DC converter or something else than can handle the current.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tying multiple LDO's together is a bad idea.  No two are going to have exactly the same output voltage regulation point.  One will take more of the load than the other, possibly stressing it more than it should be.

No, you can't assume you know the temperature response of a regulator only because you think you know something about the temperature response of its final pass element.  There is a whole feedback and control circuit in there, quite likely with temperature compensation.  Unless the datasheet explicitly tells you, you can't make any assumptions about the output voltage regulation point as a function of regulator temperature.

Some regulators have internal thermal shutdown which will prevent damage due to over current, but that's not going to be good for maintaining the output voltage.  When one shuts down, the others have to pick up the slack.  If you're lucky, the first one will come back on before the rest shut down, but that's hard to guarantee.  Even if enough always do stay on, the output supply will likely be glitched at the on/off transitions.

Even if the regulators have enough softness in their output voltages so that others will share the current, it's still not a good idea because each has its own controller, and those controllers will be fighting.  You could quite possible get oscillation of the output voltage.

The simplest way to make multiple regulators share current is to put a small resistance in series with each.  For example, separate 100 mΩ after each regulator, then the outputs of those tied together might work.  Make sure each regulator has its own output cap, which must be immediately at the regulator before the resistor.  The downside of this is that the DC resistance of the final supply will be higher than before.  Whether that's OK or not is up to you to decide.  If you tie 4 regulators together, each with their own 100 mΩ resistor, then together they only add 25 mΩ to the impedance of the regulated line.  That would be good enough in many cases.

Depending on how low your headroom voltage really is, this standard trick for making a high current regulator from a low current one might work:

[image]

This adds the B-E drop of the transistor to the headroom requirement of the regulator.

As the current thru the regulator increases, the voltage on R1 increases proportionally.  Eventually the voltage on R1 gets high enough to turn on Q1, which then starts shunting current around the regulator directly from the input to the output.  The maximum current thru the regulator will be the B-E drop of Q1 divided by R1, which should be about ¾ A in this example.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions you might want to consider:

- using a pass transistor that can handle your required current with a single LDO
- using ballast resistors to absorb some of the voltage variance between multiple LDOs
- adding a current monitoring circuit to control each LDO and adjust its output current to balance the current sharing.

Depending on your hardware, cost and complexity of the design you might consider either of the solutions, but **tying LDOs together in parallel without some load balancing circuitry will not work as others have stated.** Keep in mind if you choose to share the current between multiple LDOs the current sharing will not be 100% equal even with most complicated designs, so you must want to consider your specification, the complexity and cost, etc.

For example if you choose the simplest and cheapest solution which is to add ballast resistors in series with multiple LDOs, the current sharing between two LDOS even with 1% output voltage difference between the two might be around 70%-30%, so depending on output voltage difference between two LDOs, one of them will be handling most of the heavy work, and also there will be a voltage drop as the load current increases, which depending on what you want to do might be something to consider.

Adding a current monitoring circuitry will not be 100% perfect either, although the current sharing will significantly improve, maybe about 55%-45% between 2 LDOs depending on the design and accuracy of the circuit, even though there might always be room for improvement. But the added extra complexity, more components and cost might be something to consider depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Serial diode with small resistance to each regulator output could be a solution.

By doing so, they will share the current, drawn by load, fairly.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, canakin. The problem with your approach is that you destroy the precision voltage regulation with this approach. Note that the question was answered to the OP's satisfaction seven years ago. You can [edit] your answer at any time to improve it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can connect them in parallel. Because LDO's have a MOS structure, these Voltage regulators are not in danger to "thermal runaway", meaning if one LDO heats up, because of the positive temperature coefficient, the device conducts less and it cools again. If one LDO conducts less, the other LDO's take care of the load. Therefore they're balancing each other.

Be sure to not link them thermally.

Comment: Bad advice.  You can't extrapolate assumed temperature characteristics of the pass element to the whole regulator.